# How do i assert that parameter and result are the same type in an array of Functions (when taken as a vararg)

Tags: java, generics, lambda, casting, variadic-functions

Im trying to write a method that can take any number of objects class Function<>.

I want to use those functions to map value <T> that was passed in InputConverter constructor and return an object type R.

Example:

```
Function<String, Integer> length = String::length;

Function<Integer, String> numOfChar = charNum->{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    IntStream.generate(()->'a').limit(charNum).forEach(i -> sb.append((char) i));
    return sb.toString();
};

Function<String, String> addEnd = s->s+"FIN";

new InputConverter<String>("abc").convertBy(length, numOfChar, addEnd); //return aaaFIN
```

In this example convertBy has to map:
String to Integer using length.apply. Use the returned integer value to map it using numOfChar.apply to type String. Then use the returned String, add "FIN" and return that as an object type R (in that case String because that was a return type of the last passed function).

So in that case convertBy will result in String -> String mapping, but inside that method functions can pass values of types other then String as well (In that case, an Integer was passed)

Stupid way of doing that would be to overload method convertBy indefinitely like so:

```
public class InputConverter<T> {
    private final T toConvert;
 
    InputConverter(T toConvert) {
        this.toConvert = toConvert;
    }
 
 
    //stupid way nr 1
    public <R> R convertBy(Function<T,R> fun1) {
        return fun1.apply(toConvert);
    }
    //stupid way nr 2
    public <R, n1> R convertBy(Function<T,n1> fun1, Function<n1, R> fun2) {
        return fun1.andThen(fun2).apply(toConvert);
    }
    //stupid way nr 3
    public <R, n1, n2> R convertBy(Function<T,n1> fun1, Function<n1, n2> fun2, Function<n2, R> fun3) {
        return fun1.andThen(fun2).andThen(fun3).apply(toConvert);
    }
    //like that, but how do i assert that result of first funtion (fun1) type is the same type as parameter for functions[0]?
    public <R> R convertBy(Function<T, ?> fun1,Function<?,?>... functions){
        Function<T, ?> functionFin = fun1;
        for (Function<?, ?> fnIter : functions) {
            functionFin = functionFin.andThen(fnIter);
        }
        return functionFin.apply(this.toConvert);
    }
}
```

I want it to work with any number of functions where the first function always has to take object of the same type as passed in the constructor and returns object of any type. Then second function takes object of the type that was returned by first function and returns object any type. Then third function takes object returned by second function and returns any type and so on.
Final return type of the convertBy has to be a return type of last passed function.

Is there a way to approach this without having to overload convertBy method and without reflecton?

Comment: You can't do this in Java.  The only really good solution is to force your user to call `.andThen` instead.